# Equivalence of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please I need help proving the following question:
Given an infinite set A and a countable set B, prove that ${A}\cup{B}\sim{A}$.
I already proved the case when ${A}\cap{B}=\emptyset$ and when ${B}\subset{A}$.
I need help proving what happens when ${B}\nsubseteq{A}$ and ${A}\cap{B}\neq\emptyset$
10x in advance...

Comment: You're right. My answer only dealt with the case where $A$ and $B$ were disjoint. Use Joriki's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\cup B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$ and $A\cap(B\setminus A)=\emptyset$. Since $B$ is countable, $B\setminus A$ is countable (with any enumeration of $B$ inducing an obvious enumeration of $B\setminus A$), so you can apply the case you've already treated.

Comment: thank you, forgive me I didn't see your post before.

Answer (score 2):

Because $B$ is countable, you can find a bijection with $\mathbb N$, so call the elements $b_i$.  Similarly there is a countable subset $C$ of $A$, for which there is a bijection with $\mathbb N$, call them $c_i$.  Take $b_i \to c_{2i}, c_i \to c_{2i+1},$ rest of $A$ to itself.

Comment: Thanks @Ross, however what if ${A}\cap{B}\neq\emptyset$? does your mapping handle that case? If not how wold you define it?

Comment: @JanosAudron:  I think you are right that if $A \setminus B$ is finite this doesn't work.

Comment: joriki had provided a good solution, take a look

Comment: @JanosAudron:  Yes I noticed.  We answered just about the same time, so his came in as I posted mine.